# What is the scriptural basis for believing that animals talking was normal before the Fall?

Tags: genesis, adam-and-eve, serpent, garden-of-eden

In the book of Genesis, the serpent speaks to Eve at Genesis 3:1-5.

> 1 Now the serpent was more crafty than any beast of the field that the
> LORD God had made. And he said to the woman, “Did God really say, ‘You
> must not eat from any tree in the garden?’ ”
>
> 2 The woman answered the serpent, “We may eat the fruit of the trees of
> the garden, 3 but about the fruit of the tree in the middle of the
> garden, God has said, ‘You must not eat of it or touch it, or you will
> die.’ ”
>
> 4 “You will not surely die,” the serpent told her. 5 “For God knows that
> in the day you eat of it, your eyes will be opened and you will be
> like God, knowing good and evil.”

This happens in the the Garden of Eden. What scriptural basis is there for believing animals talking was normal before Adam and Eve left the Garden?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. We expect Biblical Basis questions here to be about the established teachings of Christian churches, not just speculations. Do you know of any churches that teach that it was normal for animals to talk before the fall, and not just the single serpent? Please [edit] this to add more information about what exactly those churches teach.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've heard radio preachers point out that since Eve doesn't seem at all surprised when the serpent speaks to her it must have been somewhat common.  It is most likely from a movement like Calvary Chapel rather than an official denomination.

Comment: @MikeBorden A notable single church would suffice too, but it's usually easier to explain to new site members that we want proof of the teaching from denominations.

Comment: It is abundantly clear from scripture that the Entity described as serpentine is later also described as adversarial (satanic), diabolic and draconian. I have never heard anyone suggest that animals commonly talked. But we do know that Balaam's ass spoke to Balaam, condemning the prophet's madness, though whether this all happened inside the unstable mind of Balaam is open to conjecture, his own deranged mind condemning his own faulty judgment.